# 2D array doesnt show data

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a module in my projects its about the finding free places in the classroom timetable. I am taking variables without problem from database. I need an array which is returns for all classroom which is how many classroom i have in DB. This classrooms also has variable time period 1 till 12 and each period has duration for example if i have in 4th period 3 duration it should write 1 2 3 x x x 7 8 9 10 11 12 and if i have another course in 9th period 2 duration it should be 1 2 3 x x x 7 8 x x 11 12. I did it in 1D array if i give the class_no in query. but it should do it more than a classroom. it shows just numbers 1..12 in 1 line.

```
$dayy = $_GET['src_day0'];
$drt = $_GET['src_duration0'];
$tm = $_GET['src_time0'];
$faculty_id = $_SESSION['faculty_id'];
$scale = "select DISTINCT t.class_no,t.time,t.duration from ttable t,class c where
          day='$dayy' AND (t.faculty='$faculty_id' OR c.faculty='$faculty_id')";
$result = $conn->query($scale);
$x = 1;
while ($rows = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $class = $rows['class_no'];
    $arr = array(
        array($x => "$class"),
        array(
            1 => " 1 ", 2 => " 2 ", 3 => " 3 ", 4 => " 4 ", 5 => " 5 ", 6 => " 6 ",
            7 => " 7 ", 8 => " 8 ", 9 => " 9 ", 10 => " 10 ", 11 => " 11 ", 12 => " 12 ",
        ));
    $x++;
}
while ($rows = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    $time = $rows['time'];
    $duration = $rows['duration'];

    $result1 = ($time + $duration);
        for($j=1;$j<$x;$j++)
         for ($i = $time; $i < $result1; $i++)
              $arr[$j][$i] = "x1";
          }

}
for ($i = 1; $i < $x; $i++) {
    for ($j = 1; $j < 13; $j++)
        echo $arr[$i][$j];
    echo "</br>";
```

Comment: Please add a better title that actually explains your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact you missbuilded your array :)

If your looking your code:

```
        $class = $rows['class_no'];
        $arr = array(
            array($x => "$class"),
            array(
                1 => " 1 ", 2 => " 2 ", 3 => " 3 ", 4 => " 4 ", 5 => " 5 ", 6 => " 6 ",
                7 => " 7 ", 8 => " 8 ", 9 => " 9 ", 10 => " 10 ", 11 => " 11 ", 12 => " 12 ",
            ));
        $x++;
```

For each iteration of the loop, you overwrite the array with a new value.

In fact, you need to create a new data and append it on the array.
A way to do it, is the following process:

```
$arr = [];
while ($rows = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  $arr[ $rows['class_no'] ] = [1 => ' 1 ', 2 => ' 2 ', /*...*/];
}

// free memory if needed

while ($rows = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  for( $i = $rows['time'] ; $i < $rows['time'] + $rows['duration'] ; $i++ ) {
    $arr[ $rows['class_no'] ][ $i ] = 'x';
  }
}
```

Here, you create an empty variable `$arr` of array type. Then, for each data on the loop, you created a new line (for each `class_no`) with the default values.
On the second loop, you iterate again on the results, but here, you take each array data by `class_no` and change the correct time value to `x`

Comment: in echo part there is a problem also i thing. Its not showing anything. Could you send the echo part for writing all array ?

Comment: How would you do that ? :p You can use function `foreach` (i.e.: `foreach( $array as $class_no => $values ){ ... }` to do that. To see the data on the array, you can use a debug function as `var_dump($variable);`